# How to tranverse through the SOAP response in eSQL

Tags: soap, ibm-integration-bus

I am new to ESQL programming language, I need bit a small help in writing it.
I have a requirement in IIB where in I receive SOAP response from SOAP Request node and send the transformed message to MQ queue.

Below is the sample input

```
<Response xmlns="http://www.xyz.fr/Retail/1.0">
         <Result xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Output>
               <Element>                  
                  <Notification>{ "employee": { "name": "sonoo", "salary": 56000, "married": true } }  </Notification>
                  <collegeID>345</collegeID>
               </Element>
               <Element>
                  <Notification> { "employee": { "name": "sonoo", "salary": 56000, "married": true } }</Notification>
                  <collegeID>123</collegeID>
               </Element>              
               </Output>
         </Result>
</Response>
```

Below is the code which I have written

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE Compute1
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        -- CALL CopyMessageHeaders();
        -- CALL CopyEntireMessage();        
        
        DECLARE myref REFERENCE TO InputRoot.XMLNSC.Response.Result.Output;
        DECLARE Count INT CARDINALITY(myref.Element[]);
        DECLARE i INT 1;
        
        WHILE (i<=Count)DO          
            SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data = FIELDVALUE(myref.Element[i].Notification);
            SET i = i + 1;  
            PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out' DELETE NONE;        
        END WHIlE;
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;

    CREATE PROCEDURE CopyMessageHeaders() BEGIN
        DECLARE I INTEGER 1;
        DECLARE J INTEGER;
        SET J = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.*[]);
        WHILE I < J DO
            SET OutputRoot.*[I] = InputRoot.*[I];
            SET I = I + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END;

    CREATE PROCEDURE CopyEntireMessage() BEGIN
        SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
        PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out1' DELETE NONE;
    END;
END MODULE;
```

In 'Count' variable I am not able to see the value, it is always showing '0'.
Count =0 but it should be 2 as per the input message.

In the input from 'Notification' field, I need to send JSON message to MQ queue using MQ Output node.

Could you please suggest is it because of namespace tagged with 'Response' field tag which I am not able to retrieve the count?

Comment: Do you have a `SOAPExtract` node after the `SOAPRequest`? If not, the payload in your `Compute` node will be under `InputRoot.SOAP` and not `InputRoot.XMLNSC`.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a Trace node to look at the message tree. Place it just before the Compute node, and set the Pattern to ${Root}. You will see exactly what the structure of the message tree is (including namespaces).

Comment: ...and yes, you will need to declare and use a namespace constant in your ESQL.